# One hundred balls in a box

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A box with a hundred white and black balls is given. Extract 3 times 5 balls, to estimate the contents of the box.

I kept thinking how this problem would be solved. I remember the classic probability exercises with a fixed white or black ball. I remember the distribution of Poisson, but I can't solve the problem. I hope you can help me with this problem.

Comment: Suppose your first draw was $4$ white balls and $1$ black, your second was $2$ white balls and $3$ black and your third was $3$ white balls and $2$ black.  What might you guess was most likely composition of the box using common sense rather than probability theory?

Answer (score 0):

First of all let's say you are interested in to find the number of white ones. Say you define the random variable X, which describes the number of the extracted white balls.
$X$ is typically binomial distributed. Hence the parameter $n$ is big enough and the probability parameter $p$ is small, it makes possible to approximate those distribution with the Poisson distribution.
From the 3 extractions you can calculate an expected value, which is the $\lambda$ parameter of the Poisson distribution $E(X)=\lambda$. After this you can calculate the ratio of the white balls for every $k$.

Answer (score 0):

If the portion $p$ of the (e.g.) white balls is not "extreme", that is far from $0$ and $100 \%$, then you may assume that extracting five balls without replacement is not going to alter the proportion of balls more that the confidence bounds that you shall establish in any case.
So you can approximately take that the extractions are made with replacement, and so that is like estimating the $p$ of a coin upon 15 tosses.

For that you can have a look at [Binomial proportion confidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) or at the article on [checking a coin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checking_whether_a_coin_is_fair).